# Displaying 450 image files from SDCard at 30fps on android

Tags: android, image, animation, video, ffmpeg

I am trying to develop an app that takes a 15 seconds of video, allows the user to apply different filters, shows the preview of the effect, then allows to save the processed video to sdcard. I use ffmpeg to split the video into JPEG frames, apply the desired filter using GPUImage to all the frames, then use ffmpeg to encode the frames back to a video. Everything works fine except the part where user selects the filter. When user selects a filter, the app is supposed to display the preview of the video with the filter applied. Though 450 frames get the filter applied fairly quick, displaying the images sequentially at 30 fps (to make the user feel the video is being played) is performing poorly. I tried different approaches but the maximum frame rate I could attain even on the fastest devices is 10 to 12 fps.

The AnimationDrawable technique doesn't work in this case because it requires the entire images to be buffered into memory which in this case is huge. App crashes.

The below code is the best performing one so far (10 to 12 fps).

```
package com.example.animseqvideo;
import ......

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Handler handler;
    Runnable runnable;
    final int interval = 33; // 30.30 FPS
    ImageView myImage;
    int i=0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

        handler = new Handler();
        runnable = new Runnable(){
            public void run() {

                i++;  if(i>450)i=1;

                File imgFile = new  File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/com.example.animseqvideo/image"+ String.format("%03d", i)   +".jpg");
                if(imgFile.exists()){
                    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
                    myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
                }
//SOLUTION EDIT - MOVE THE BELOW LINE OF CODE AS THE FIRST LINE OF run() AND FPS=30 !!!

                handler.postDelayed(runnable, interval);
            }
        };
        handler.postAtTime(runnable, System.currentTimeMillis()+interval);
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, interval);
    }
}
```

I understand that the process of getting an image from SDCard, decoding it, then displaying it onto the screen involves the performance of the SDCard reading, the CPUs performance and graphics performance of the device. But I am wondering if there is a way I could save a few milliseconds in each iteration. Any suggestion would be of great help at this point.

Comment: you can cache the next image(s) while you are showing the current. take a look at this https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Bad ! Found the culprit. Being used to NSTimer on iOS, I overlooked the importance of the line of code :

```
handler.postDelayed(runnable, interval);
```

That code responsible for scheduling the next frame process was being executed AFTER the current frame getting read from the SDCard, decoded and displayed on to the imageview.

ie. If the entire process of displaying the current frame took 25 milliseconds, the next frame processing would be scheduled after 25+33 = 58ms after previous frame.

I moved that line of code to the first line of the run{} method of the runnable thread , and BINGO !! FPS raised to 24-30 FPS even on a $100 android device.

Anyways thanks to @Valentin, @Pedro Bernardo and @Shashika for pointing out some valid possible solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I also did a similar thing. I used a ValueAnimator. The images is an array of the image ids. eg: R.drawable.park1

```
ValueAnimator animation = ValueAnimator.ofInt(0,44);
            animation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
            animation.setDuration(1000);
            animation.setRepeatCount(200);
            animation.addUpdateListener(new AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                int i;          
                public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                    Log.i("TAG", "::onAnimationUpdate: "+(++i)+" value = "+animation.getAnimatedValue());               
                    mImageViewPreview.setImageResource(images[(Integer) animation.getAnimatedValue()]);
                    mImageViewPreview.invalidate();

                    if(mImageViewPreview.getVisibility()!=View.VISIBLE){
                        animation.cancel();                 
                    }
                }           

            });
            animation.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are correct in saying that the performance of SDCard reading is slow. In fact look at how many things you want done - creating a new file from an external location, decoding it and creating a new bitmap. And all this done on the UI thread.

I don't know how big your images are but have you tried possibly preloading some of them, putting them in a list and then just picking them from that list and displaying them in your handler code?

I realize storing 450 images in memory is quite a lot but the task could probably be split up. Say you have preload 100 bitmaps and start displaying them, and then have an Async Task preloading the other 100 into the next list(or possibly the same list) at the same time.